# Xamarin Forms Button Released not triggered if you move the finger a little while the button is still pressed

Tags: xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Xamarin.Forms.Buttons. I want my app to execute an action when the user presses the button, and a different action when the user releases it. The problem is that once you have pressed the button if you move the finger(while you are still touching the screen), the released event will never be triggered even when you release the finger. When you move the finger, the button makes the animation like it was released/lostFocused but the "Released" event is not triggered. If you press and release again the same button without moving the finger, both events are triggered.

I would like always to know when the user has finished pressing a button.

Is there a way to make the "Released" event trigger in that situation?
Can I make the button has a "IsPressed" property or something simillar, so I can check it?
Can I check for example a "Screen.IsPressed" to know that the whole screen is not touched anywhere?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: unable to reproduce this, the released event is always triggered, As soon as you lift your finger from the screen, the release event will be triggered, Is your XF version up to date?

Comment: **The problem is that once you have pressed the button if you move the finger(while you are still touching the screen), the released event will never be triggered even when you release the finger.** I am not clear about this problem, so can you provide some code here, it is helpful for us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. You are right. If I make a new project with a simple button, I am not finding that problem either. In the project that I have the problem, my button is part of a ViewCell that is part of a ListView. Maybe that is causing the problem.
By the way, I was able to solve the problem using a CustomButton.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/423607#Comment_423607

Comment: @DanelGoikoetxea If you have solved your problem, please share your solution here and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I make a new project with a simple button, I am not finding that problem either. In the project that I have the problem, my button is part of a ViewCell that is part of a ListView. Maybe that is causing the problem. By the way, I was able to solve the problem using a CustomButton.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/423607#Comment_423607